# htaccess 301 directive for SSL

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, redirect, https, virtualhost

I am trying to allow customers to have multiple domains, but `301` them to their "permanent" domain for canonical reasons.  I am getting some strange activity, and am positive it has to do with my syntax, however I don't know where the issue resides.

I have a main domain - let's call it `permanent_site.com`  **Note:** I have an SSL installed and working for "permanent domain"

I have multiple non-permanent domains that I want to permanently redirect to the "permanent domain".  Now lets say I have 2 non primary domains: `non_p_domain1.com` and `non_p_domain2.com`.

Should this not work?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
   ServerName    non_p_domain1.com
   ServerAlias   non_p_domain2.com
   Redirect 301 / https://permanent_site.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName      permanent_site.com
    DocumentRoot    /path/to/html

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
    SSLHonorCipherOrder on
    SSLCertificateFile /path/to/ssl/permanent_site.com.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to//ssl/permanent_site.com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/ssl/permanent_site.com.ca.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

The whole point in doing it this way is to prevent someone from hitting `https://non_p_domain1.com` and being fed an "unsecure page".  Instead, I want them redirected to the permanent domain before they hit the html directory that has all the `.htaccess` directives.

Comment: What happens exactly when requesting `https://non_p_domain1.com`?

Comment: It show "This page is unsecure" warning in Chrome.

Comment: That's a _browser_ warning due to an invalid SSL cert during the initial handshake when making a request over HTTPS. The request never reaches your server, unless the user accepts the invalid cert (which they should not do).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> from hitting `https://non_p_domain1.com` and being fed an "unsecure page"

All the non-primary domains also need to have an SSL cert installed. By the sounds of it, they don't?

If not, then the client won't (or should not) connect to your server, so they never see the redirect.

Comment: So, if I have 700 websites, and roughly 2-3 domains per .. That's a huge cost center .. That's what we were trying to avoid is having to have SSLs for domains that for all intents and purposes are just CNAMEs  -- So there is no way to make `https://foo` forward to `https://bar` without having an SSL for both?  Is that correct?

Comment: No way without a valid SSL cert. If you could then that would be a serious flaw in the HTTPS security model. When making a request over HTTPS, the browser needs to establish a secure connection before your server receives the request. If the server does not receive the request then no redirect occurs.

Comment: Without an SSL cert then the only redirect you can do is from `http://non_p_domain1.com` (insecure) to `https://permanent_site.com/`. (Without incurring browser warnings.)

Comment: You can get free SSL certs with "Let's Encrypt", but there are limits. Maybe just free certs for the non-primary domains? (Then you also need to cover www subdomains etc.?)